# Amazon VPC unable to access internet from private subnet

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc

I have setup an Amazon Public+Private subnet VPC. There are two instances in public subnet:

- Amazon Nat instance
- OpenVPN Access Server

I am able to setup VPN to the internal private subnet (10.0.1.0/24) through (10.0.0.0/16) network. But i am unable to access internet from private subnet (10.0.1.0/24).

Though, the routing is configured properly as it should be.

The Gateway to access internet is set to the OpenVPN Access server, but internet access is not going beyond that server.

Do i have to enable NAT in iptables on OpenVPN server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never mind.
It was a routing table that was not configured properly and subnet was not associated with routing table properly.